# Omission of direct object

Tags: objects

There are some verbs that in English don't take any object direct like "to promise" in: I promise; to know: I know. Besides, on replying a question like: Are you sure? Yes, I am. Translated into Spanish, that would be the neuter pronoun it- written "lo" into Spanish.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  "Yes, I am."  and "Yes, I am sure." are both valid English.

Comment: Can you make your examples clearer?  Which words should be in quotes?  Which words are the concepts that you are providing examples of?

Comment: Umm, you didn't actually ask a question. Except "Would anybody be able to reply to my question?"

Comment: An example of my doubt is: the verb "to promise" on conjugating it: I promise, I know, I tell you. All of them have a complete meaning in English without the direct object, but the verb doesn't have  any object to support on. In Spanish that is very weird and senseless, too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you may be struggling with is an *implied object* due to context.
If you went up to *someone* and said

> I promise
> I know

They would ask you "Promise what?", "Know what?"

Your examples are usually said in a given context the object of which was omitted

> Do you promise to do your homework?
> I promise *(to do my homework)*.

> Do you know about the moon's orbit?
> I know *(about it)*.

> D you remember his name?
> I remember *(his name)*.